# Finding the number of ten letter combinations from the set of {A,B,C} repetitions allowed:

Tags: probability, combinatorics

a. with at least one of each letter

```
the length is 10 with a 3 elements to choose from the given set. 
3 of the 10 slots will be taken up by A,B, and C. With 7 remaining, any 
letter could take up those spots so:
The answer will be (7+3-1 choose 3-1), which is (9 choose 2).
```

b. with at least two of each letter

```
With two of each letter, 6 letters will take up 10 slots no matter
what. So 10-6 = 4 and then we have 3 to choose from so (4 + 3 - 1 choose 3-1). 
We get (6 choose 2) for the answer.
```

c. at least one A, two Bs, and three Cs

```
1A + 2B + 3C will take up 6 spots.
(4+ 3-1 choose 3-1) which is (6 choose 2).
```

d. any number of each letter

```
10 choose 3.
```

e. at least one A and at least two Bs

```
so with at least 1 A and two Bs taking up a total of 3 slots.
10 - 3 = 7. (7 + 3 - 1 choose 3 - 1) which is (9 choose 2).
```

Then to find the probability, I would divide each total by 10 choose 3

I'm really not sure about any of these combinations, if someone could explain why I'm wrong I would be thankful.

Edit:Answers were modified.

Comment: Your approach to part $a$ is not correct.  You are only counting those with $A,B,C$ in three prescribed slots.

Comment: hmm then all the rest are also probably wrong as well. Then, for $a$, would it be (3 choose 1)(2 choose 1)(1 choose 1)(3^7)?

Comment: No...I'd say the best was to start with all combinations, $3^{10}$, then subtract those missing a fixed letter, then add back those that miss two fixed letters.

Comment: So for the first one, since there is only at least one of each, I'm left with 9 choose 2. Is that correct?

Using the algorithm of (k-1 choose n-1) where k is the length of the combinations and n is the elements of the set. 

for $b$, using the same algo, we get (6 choose 2)

Comment: Not sure where you are getting that.  Stick with my suggestion.  Apply the [Principle of Inclusion and Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  Start with all the words, $3^{10}$.  Then subtract those that miss one fixed letter.  Then add back those that miss two fixed letters.

Comment: As a general suggestion:  if you have a method you think might work, try it for three letter words, or four letter words.  Those cases are small enough that you can do the count by hand and test it against what your method yields.

Comment: @lulu I think it would be false to use the the terminology "words" as we are only concerned with the combinations of the letters and not their arrangements

Comment: @SirJMP  Ah, I was, of course, assuming that the order mattered.  I see that this isn't stated.  Thanks!  In that case, the problem is much easier.  We just need to count triples $\{a,b,c\}$ such that $a+b+c=10$ and $a,b,c≥1$.

Comment: Precisely!!...all the parts of the above question then can be solved by multinomial theorem

Comment: Johnson u got all ur solutions wrong...u have assumed it to be a permutation problem....all u need to do is to find the no. of integral solutions to the eqn. x + y + z=10......where x,y and z take suitable values according to the given constraint.....further the solutions can be obtained using multinomial theorem....

Comment: i have gone through each question and am more confident about the answers. I just had to practice on a 3 letter word first and i just adjusted the answers accordingly to understand it better.

Comment: Yeh...all ur new solutions in the edited answer are correct...